# Converting Vector looking string into vector values [python]

Tags: python, string, vector

I have a list of vector looking strings i.e.: '[1, 5, 7, 2, n]' and want to convert them to a vector, I tried:

```
import numpy as np

string = '[1, 4, 7, 42]' ##(or in my case the result of os.popen(cmd).read() )
vector = np.fromstring(string, sep=', ')

print vector 
[]
```

The same if I change the sep value to ' ', how do I get it distinguish the values correctly?

Comment: Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be really lazy, use the `np.matrix` constructor:

```
>>> np.array(np.matrix(string)).ravel()
array([ 1,  4,  7, 42])
```

or even less clean but shorter:

```
>>> np.matrix(string).A[0]
array([ 1,  4,  7, 42])
```

Answer (score 1):

A naive but simple approach would be

```
string = "[1, 2, 3, 4]"
arr = [int(i.strip()) for i in string[1:-1].split(",")]
```

you can then convert that to a numpy array

```
np.array(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem are the brackets.

```
>>> np.fromstring('1, 4, 7, 42', sep=',')
array([  1.,   4.,   7.,  42.])
```

I suggest that you use `ast.literal_eval` and then convert the result to a numpy array.

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> np.array(literal_eval('[1, 4, 7, 42]'))
array([ 1,  4,  7, 42])
```